# How to run unit testing for an Angular app on Gitlab CI?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to run unit testing on my Angular library using the Gitlab CI. The tests are working and succeeding on my local machine, but they don't see to be run at all on Gitlab. I have tried editing my test script to run the steps described [here](https://medium.com/@JohanPujol/test-unitaires-en-angular-avec-angular-cli-et-gitlab-ci-6c6124dfe7b9), but to no avail. Here is the log of my test stage :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.8.0~beta.44.g57df0d52 (57df0d52)
  on blue-4.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default J2nyww-s
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 00:33
Using Docker executor with image node:latest ...
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:f8c8d04432c3686347434420abcc20646237c5685b4b11a7db63df7acb866cd6 for node:latest with digest node@sha256:a0590a265b222387d756ba357c4a9875778f1a7638ac011f3fb4942d3b7ae5c0 ...
Preparing environment 00:03
Running on runner-j2nyww-s-project-33286021-concurrent-0 via runner-j2nyww-s-shared-1644574459-102eb0f3...
Getting source from Git repository 00:03
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/xxxxx/my-project/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 6c0fbcdf as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache 00:15
Checking cache for 9e7cd7eec847386573b03db5adf9ef87d7c957c2...
Downloading cache.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/xxxx/cache
Successfully extracted cache
Checking cache for main...
Downloading cache.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/xxxx/main 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:f8c8d04432c3686347434420abcc20646237c5685b4b11a7db63df7acb866cd6 for node:latest with digest node@sha256:a0590a265b222387d756ba357c4a9875778f1a7638ac011f3fb4942d3b7ae5c0 ...
$ npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
added 1308 packages, and audited 1524 packages in 32s
129 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
43 moderate severity vulnerabilities
To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix
To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.
$ { # collapsed multi-line command
@my-group:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=[MASKED]
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxx/packages/npm/:_authToken=[MASKED]
$ cd projects/my-lib
$ npm test
> @my-group/my-lib@1.1.6 test
> ng test
Node.js version v17.5.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
11 02 2022 10:16:45.662:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
11 02 2022 10:16:45.765:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.3.15 server started at http://localhost:9876/
11 02 2022 10:16:45.772:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
11 02 2022 10:16:45.784:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
11 02 2022 10:16:45.785:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
  Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
11 02 2022 10:17:09.953:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
```

It then remains stuck on that last instruction.
Here is my test stage :

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd projects/my-lib
    - npm test
```

The new test script I tried :

```
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/karma start karma.conf.js"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I remember running into a similar problem a while back. As you can see in the log output, the script is looking for a binary file for your browser, trying to launch it but none could be found. Looking into using headless browsers (e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think I am almost there, but how should I install Chrome Headless (for example) in the Gitlab CI ?

Comment: I see you're using `Docker`. I think the following link would help you: https://purple.telstra.com/blog/run-angular-unit-tests-in-gitlab-ci.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick :)